# Can I write around 10MB of value against a single key in azure redis cache

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

Can I write around 10MB of value (JSON Data as a string) against a key (string - xyz) in Azure redis cache

Size- Standard 1 GB
Version - 4.0.14

I am able to insert 3MB of value , but while inserting 7MB of value it gives network error.

I am using **StackExchange.Redis.2.1.58** client from .net console app.

Comment: What is the network error?

Comment: **StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: 'An unknown error occurred when writing the message'**

StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An unknown error occurred when writing the message
  Source=StackExchange.Redis
  StackTrace:
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2805
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint serve

Answer (score 0):

From [Redis website](https://redis.io/topics/data-types):

> Strings are the most basic kind of Redis value. Redis Strings are
> binary safe, this means that a Redis string can contain any kind of
> data, for instance a JPEG image or a serialized Ruby object.
>
> A String value can be at max 512 Megabytes in length.

Answer (score 0):

You could put 'syncTimeout' parameter in ConnectionString like this "RedisConfiguration": {"ConnectionString": "mycache.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,**syncTimeout=150000**"," DatabaseNumber ": 1}. This parameter sets the "Time (ms) to allow synchronous operations", as can be seen at https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html. I had this problem when I stored items that took more than 5 seconds to be processed, since this is the default value. You can try increasing this value using the parameter inserted in the connection string. I hope I can help you with this, regards.